# global objective

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Suppose we have two content packages, CP_A with objectivesGlobalToSystem = true and CP_B with objectivesGlobalToSystem = false. CP_A creates a global objective with id of g-obj and CP_B also creates a global objective with id of g-obj. I have two questions?

1. Are these two global objectives the same?
2. If CP_C wants to read the status of g-obj, in this case which global objective should be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Are these two global objectives the same?

No, they're not. g-obj of
    CP_B is global to CP_B only and it's not accessable from outside. g-obj of CP_A is global to all courses except CP_B,
    provided that other courses have objectivesGlobalToSystem set to
    true which is the default value.

> 1. If CP_C wants to read the status of g-obj, in this case which global
>      objective should be read?

It reads the values stored in g-obj of
    CP_A only.

Comment: I'm not good in English and I couldn't understand the following section of your answer:


`provided that other courses have objectivesGlobalToSystem set to true which is the default value.`

Comment: It means: The default value of objectivesGlobalToSystem is true, if it isn't changed, all courses on the LMS will have access to global objectives.

Comment: Does objectivesGlobalToSystem have any impact on readSatisfiedStatus and readNormalizedMeasure attributes?

Comment: When objectivesGlobalToSystem is set to true, those values become available to other courses.